# SocketException during Full GC

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I am seeing a strange behavior in my server logs where, everything time Full GC happens, I see a SocketException is thrown. Is this an expected behavior ?

jdk 1.7
jboss 6.1

Comment: It could be.  Show us the stacktrace

Comment: ***What*** ` SocketException` is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scenario where this is expected behaviour:

1. `Socket` is opened
2. Application wraps `SocketOutputStream` in `BufferedOutputStream`
3. Application writes some data to the `BufferedOutputStream`
4. Application leaks the `Socket` > `SocketOutputStream` > `BufferedOutputStream` stack ... without closing it.
5. Time passes ...
6. The remote server / client times out the interaction and closes the TCP stream.
7. Time passes ...
8. The GC runs, finds the `BufferedOutputStream` and attempts to finalize it
9. The `finalize()` method attempts to flush the buffered data.
10. That triggers an exception, because the data cannot be flushed to a closed TCP/IP connection.

Comment: VG but it would trigger an `IOException: connect reset.`